# MICROSOFT ACCOUNT lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting the following error in in visualstudio.com when accessing nuget feed:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"4d90beec-a2e5-4f8f-8108-23480a7b53f8\
>       MICROSOFT-ACCOUNT lacks permission to complete this action. 
>       You need to have 'ReadPackages'.","typeName":
>       "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi.FeedNeedsPermissionsException,
>
> ```
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi",
> "typeKey":"FeedNeedsPermissionsException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer works for most cases. But if you are still getting that issue check that

- The user has access to the correct project (organization settings)
- The user is also part of the team for that project (within the project settings)

Answer (score 1):

Set the correct access level in TFS.
The default access level is set to “Stakeholder”.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/06/tfs-2017-nuget-publisher-task-fails-with-401-unauthorized-exception/
Also more information here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4319